# Testar CRUD feito em Laravel com phpUnit

Tags: php, laravel, testes, testes-automatizados, phpunit

Caros,

tenho um CRUD simples, aparecendo somente o campo descrição na tela, e o código é gerado pelo banco.

Eu quero montar um script para testar:
- inclusão
- ver se aparece no index
- alteração
- exclusão

Porém não estou conseguindo nem abrir a endereço pois dá erro.
Eu desenvolvi em Laravel e tenho que acessar após o login.

Vejam o código que desenvolvi para testar:

```
$user = User::find(14);
$response = $this->actingAs($user)->get('/login');
$response->assertRedirect('/home');

$response = $this->get('/dfutebol/atividades');
$response->assertStatus(200);

// cria o novo objeto
$obj = new Atividades(['atividade_descricao' => 'Atividade Teste']);
$response = $this->get('/dfutebol/atividades/create', $obj);
$response->assertStatus(200);
```

E me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::get() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sade\tests\Feature\AtividadeTest.php on line 29

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sade\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests.php:164
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sade\tests\Feature\AtividadeTest.php:29
```

A linha 29 é a linha abaixo:

```
$response = $this->get('/dfutebol/atividades/create', $obj);
```

Será que alguém pode me dar uma dica?

Comment: O erro ja lhe diz, ele espera um array com os valores, e não o objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Como já diz o erro, ele espera um array e está sendo passado um objeto. Transforme esse objeto em um array antes de enviá-lo

```
$obj = new Atividades(['atividade_descricao' => 'Atividade Teste']);
$response = $this->get('/dfutebol/atividades/create', $obj->toArray()); //Objeto está sendo transformado em array
$response->assertStatus(200);
```